# ubuntu apache set https error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, https

this is '000-default' file's content:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myServeName
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    #<Directory "/var/www">
     #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      #  AllowOverride None
       # Order allow,deny
       # Allow from all
    #</Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/test/judianer-error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/test/judianer-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

and apache can use,browser can access http:(myserveName),but when i add the content bottom:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/214399318900951.pem
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        ServerName myserveName
        #<Directory />
         # Options FollowSymLinks
          #AllowOverride All
#       </Directory>
#       <Directory /var/www/>
#       Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#       AllowOverride None
#       Order allow,deny
#       allow from all
        # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
        # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
        #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
#       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my apache can't start.how toi solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an SSLCertificateKeyFile

And check the LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_ssl.so

If you want to use the directory www/test, use:

```
<Directory /var/www/test> 
Options FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: hello.i edit conf.but https:myserveName still goes to 'www'(dictionary) ,i want to set to the 'www/test'(dictionary).how to edit ?and now my conf is

Comment: Is apache start now?

Comment: yes.and now my conf is: <VirtualHost wenjunlin.xyz:443>
    #SSLEngine on
        #SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/214399318900951.pem
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        ServerName www.wenjunlin.xyz
        #<Directory />
         # Options FollowSymLinks
          #AllowOverride All
#       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: i know my error.I should edit 443 trunk's conf in 'default-ssl.conf',not in '000-default.conf'.Still thank you very much